# create a function with dot: myfunc.print("Hello World") in python

Tags: python, function

how do you define dotted function?

i try this:

```py
def myfunc.print(value)
  print(value);
```

but it's said "Invalid syntax"

Comment: "how do you define dotted function" I don't understand what this is supposed to mean. How do you want to *use* the function? Can you show some examples of what you are talking about? Also - have you tried following a Python language tutorial? Stack Overflow is not intended for teaching the language fundamentals.

Comment: i mean, a function name that contains dot. example: `myfunc.print` did you see the ***DOT**??

Comment: No, I mean, why do you think a function name should be able to contain a dot? For example, did you see code that calls a function that way? In those cases, the dot is **not** part of the name of any function. It cannot be. It is a separate piece of syntax - which you should learn about by following a tutorial.

Comment: im just curious...

Comment: on javascript, i know how to do it: `var myfunc = {}; myfunc.print = function(val){console.log(val)};`

Comment: In those javascript cases, the `.` isn't part of the name of a function *either*. Instead, you are attaching a *method* to an *object* and then using it. It works similarly in Python. However, you cannot expect to research any topic in any programming language without first putting in the effort to learn *what things are called*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In python, and in many other languages, the "dot" syntax is a product of code organizational structure.  So, `X.Y` tells python to look for `Y` *inside of* `X`.  There are actually a few ways to do this.  You can define a class which organizes a set of functions and properties within the class or its associated objects (as @Samwise's answer shows).  You can also create a new file "myfunc.py", and have one of the functions defined in that file be `def print(): pass` - then when you `import myfunc` in another file you can access `myfunc.print`.  In any case, the dot represents a "belonging" relationship, so you need to have your `print` function "belong" to the `myfunc` containing structure in some way.

Comment: **RecursionError** appears in `def print(val):` then `print(val)`. i try to call it but error appears

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way:

```
>>> class myfunc:
...     print = print
...
>>> myfunc.print("foo")
foo
```

In this example, `myfunc` is actually a class, and `print` is a class attribute (which is initialized to point to the `print` function).